# How Do I Hide (or make read-only) Certain Fields in a Task Form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, content-type, tasks

In my task form, I can't figure out how to hide '% Complete' and/or 'Task Status' without losing the ability to complete the task.  I am using a custom content type with only one option, 'Task Complete', and if I hide those fields, selecting 'Task Complete' won't allow my workflow to progress.

If I could just make those fields so they were only viewable by users, but editable by workflow, that would be helpful.  Really, just making every part of my task form read only, with the exception of my 'Task Complete' button would accomplish what I'm after I think.  Thank you!

Comment: Is this SP2010 or 2013?

Comment: It is SP2013...generally using 2013 WF as well (if that makes any difference?)...

Comment: Hello.. I have the same question as yours, were you able to hide the two fields - (% Complete' and/or 'Task Status) on the task form.

Answer (score 1):

So here's what you want to do:  Create a javascript file that has an JQuery entry for document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //This should hide the row, but may only hide the label
   $("nobr:contains('% Complete')").hide();
   //this hides the text box
   $("input[title='% Complete']").hide();
}
```

Once you have done that for each of the fields you want to hide you save the file into a location in your site assets.  Also download and save a version of jquery.min file.  Maybe create a folder for js files.

Then do the following:

1. In the list view (for the tasks list) within Designer Edit the form you wish to update.
2. Click on Preview in Browser
3. Click on Settings – Edit Page
4. Edit Form Web Part
5. Under Miscellaneous add the following to the JS Link:  ~site/SiteAssets/JSFiles/jquery-1.11.1.min.js|~site/SiteAssets/JSFiles/modTaskForm.js

What that does is tells the task form to load the jquery file and you js file for manipulation of the task form.  My code may not be spot on, but should be close enough to get you what you need.

Hope this helps.

Dave

Comment: I still don't get it why people are still using jQuery these days, especially with SharePoint which provides lots of Javascript libraries to do the same things. The best way to hide fields or make them read-only is using **Client Side Rendering** (in short, CSR). Check a couple of examples [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a). As for making fields read-only on the edit form, see [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Sample-8-List-add-and-edit-d228b751).

Comment: I second that. jQuery was great in 2006 when it solved many cross-browser Issues. All modern browsers support ES-5 and can do all this basic jQuery stuff with the same amount of typing. The JSlink answer itself is using 50% of modern 2013 technologies and then reverting back to 50% of dinosaur technology. Learn that new 50% CSR, and use [the Cisar Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en) for it.

Comment: Thanks guys.  You have given me something to review.  I have been in SP for quite some time, but let's just say client side dev was not where I worked.  I can only post what I know or have seen myself.  Will be looking into what you have posted myself so I am better informed and can improve how I do things myself.